# Is there more efficient way to get one dimensional list from list containing arrays nested to any level (infinite dimensions)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, flatten

### Flatten the Array

```
def isiterable(anyObject):
    if hasattr(anyObject, '__iter__') and not type(anyObject) is str:
        if len(anyObject) > 0:
            if not next(iter(anyObject)) == anyObject:
                return True
    else:
        return False

def flattenArrayN(inputArray, flatList=0):
    if flatList == 0:
        flatList = []
    for item in inputArray:
        if isiterable(item):
            if type(item) is dict:
                for pair in item.items():
                    flattenArrayN(pair, flatList)
            else:
                flattenArrayN(item, flatList)
        else:
            flatList.append(item)
    
    return flatList
```

The code works for an type of array, which is very important.

Run it on online IDE - [Link](https://repl.it/KfPl/2)